# Angular/Typescript - mapping object to user defined properties

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, mapping

I'm currently working on a component in ng2 which should present data provided by parameter (it will be Array of Objects). The problem is, that property names of the objects in provided array are not always the same ie.

Array 1:

```
{emplNo: 1, emplName: "John", emplCompany:"Volvo" }
```

and in different scenario Array2:

```
{employeeNo: 1, employeeName: "John", companyName:"Volvo" }
```

My idea was to create input properties for each of property name and then somehow use those names to map provided array into new array with static properties and the use this new array to present data in my component something like this:

```
interface mappedObjectInterface { 
  number: number,
  name: string,
  companyName: string
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let item of mappedItemsSource">
        {{item.number}}, {{item.name}}, {{item.companyName}}
    </div>

  `
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() ItemsSource: Array<Objects>; //provided Array
@Input() numberPropertyName: string;  // name of number property
@Input() namePropertyName: string;    // name of name property
@Input() companyNamePropertyName: string;    // name of companyName property
}

mapItemsSource(numberName, nameName, companyNameName) {
    let mappedItemsSource:mappedObjectInterface  = this.ItemsSource.map(item => ({
        number: item.numberName, //here I want to use the  property name provided by numberPropertyName input parameter
        name: item.nameName, //here I want to use the  property name provided by namePropertyName input parameter
        companyName: item.companyNameName, //here I want to use the  property name provided by campanynamePropertyName input parameter

    }));
}

ngOnInit() {        
    this.mapItemsSource(this.numberPropertyName, this.namePropertyName, this.companyNamePropertyName)
}
```

and an example code to use this component would be something like:

```
<my-component [ItemsSource]="Data"
              [numberPropertyName]="'emplNo'"
              [namePropertyName]="'emplName'"
              [companyPropertyName]="'emplCompanyName'">    
</my-component>
```

Could someone tell me if that's a correct way of dealing with this task or should I do it in other way? Unfortunately, according to my team leader opinion - creating interface to control provided ItemsSource structure is not an option. The component must convert Array by itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Make your interface optional to something like this

```
interface mappedObjectInterface { 
  emplNo?: number,
  employeeNo?: number,
  emplName?: string,
  employeeName?: string,
  companyName?: string,
  emplCompany?: string
}
```

**Update**

If you are unsure of the type of key that might come , the only thing that might help you here is by not using an interface and going by Array index numbers i:e  0 , 1 , 2 .

Comment: I just showed 2 examples of property names. There could much more of them and I'm not able to tell what names will occur in the future. Even if I make optional properties in the interface, I still don't know what properties I need to display in my template.

Comment: @Morgoth upodated the answer